# Handling tap on custom cell on UITableView don't happened

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have ViewController with TableView. For this TableView i wrote custom TableViewCell class. 
My cell contain only 2 labels.
I need to get tap on this cells and then to do something. I tried with

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and some alerts inside it, but nothing happened. I can't use some methods like using invisible button on cell because i have to get some data from TableView like indexPath etc. which i won't get in my customCell class.

Comment: On the cell added ImageView or not ? If not then check it's delegate and datasource settle or not ?

Comment: Edited ask. My cell contains 2 labels only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead of using `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Usage of didDeselect was only because of my inattention. Thank you. But it didn't help.

Comment: did you set tableview delegate and datasource @user3441605

Comment: No, i didn't. I know that but my invariable inattention... Thank you a lot!